# How to replace findOneById in TypeORM now it is deprecated

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, generics, typeorm

I am writing generic functions for my database calls so don't know the ID field name. This was fine when we could use findOneById.

Is there a way now to do an equivalent findOneById where we don't know the primary key field name(s)?

This is basically how my code works now. But it will stop working when they remove the findOneById function and I've got to find another way to do it.

e.g.

```
async function softDeleteItem(
    itemId: number,
    entityClass: ObjectType<Entity> | EntitySchema<Entity> | string,
    deletedBy: string
): Promise<boolean> {
    const repo = db.getRepository(entityClass);

    const itemToDelete = await repo.findOneById(itemId);

    (itemToDelete as ISoftDeletable).deletedBy = deletedBy;

    await repo.softDelete(resourceEntityToDelete);
}
```

---- Update ----
The only way I have managed to achieve what I want is with queryBuilder and pass in the name of the ID property (this could be multiple ID properties, in which case loop through them and use andWhere() for each one):

```
async function softDeleteItem(
    itemId: number,
    itemIdKey: string,
    ...
): Promise<boolean> {
    ...

    const itemToDelete = await repo
        .createQueryBuilder('entity')
        .where(`entity.${itemIdKey as string} = :itemId`, { itemId })
        .getOneOrFail();

    ...
}
```

But I'm still wondering if there's a way to do it with just an ID value, as using findOneById was more readable and concise?

Comment: According to the changelog `Repository and EntityManager method .findOneById is deprecated and will be removed in next 0.3.0 version. Use findOne(id) method instead now.`

ref https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: So `findOne(itemId)` should work in your case

Comment: findOne(itemId) isn't part of the findOne or findOneBy type signatures. It looks like they've made it type safe so the only way to do it is by findOne({where: {propertyName: value}}) or findOneBy({propertName: value}).

Comment: I see. Looking at your update and definition of `.findOneBy`, I'd suggest passing in an object in your function instead of itemId and key separately. Since `.findOneBy` accepts a `Partial` object of your entity, all you need to pass in is the properties on which you want to query. This also gives you more flexibility to pass in more than just an id in future